# Setup multiple mod_clusters on same server

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6, mod-cluster

I have 2 servers on which I want to setup a clusterized environment like describe in the diagram bellow.

[image: Jboss Domain]

Basically I have a single web application that need to be deployed multiple times, once for every one of our clients. My idea is to create a cluster for each client, distributing the load between the 2 machines I got.

Each client would have its own server group, and every server group would be composed of 2 jboss servers, one on each machine.

I was able to configure the environment for a single server group. I believe my idea is feasible. The only thing I couldn't get my head around is how to configure multiple mod_clusters on the same server.

My mod_cluster is up and running, listening to port 10001 and distributing requests between machines. My question is, how should I configure mod_cluster so it will listen to multiple ports (10001, 10002 and 10003) and direct requests to server group associated with that port?

This is my mod_cluster configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 10.211.55.7:10001>

  <Directory />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.211.55.
  </Directory>


  # This directive allows you to view mod_cluster status at URL http://10.211.55.4:10001/mod_cluster-manager
  <Location /mod_cluster-manager>
   SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 10.211.55.
  </Location>

  KeepAliveTimeout 60
  MaxKeepAliveRequests 0

  ManagerBalancerName other-server-group
  AdvertiseFrequency 5

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I ended up using mod_proxy to configure a load balancer. By setting up multiple Virtual Hosts I was able to achieve what I needed.